# Scrolling first occurence to top position inside div

Tags: javascript, html

After I clicked on link, which navigate to another page I have to scroll the first (the earliest) alarm occurrence (which is marked as a red text) at the top of "tbody" div. Each row have `id='tab_content'` and a table data `class = 'td_list_row_center'`. When alarm occurs, tds are changing color from black to red and a name `class = 'td_list_row_center font-red"`.

I've tried to handle red occurrence and if it was found, scroll at the top inside "tbody" div. The second row should be with black font (non-alarm)

```
<script>
    function scrollToFirstRedAlarmOccurence(red_occurrence) {
        $('tbody').animate({
            scrollTop: red_occurrence.offset().top
        }, 2000);
    }

    var red_occurrence = document.getElementsByClassName("td_list_row_center font-red");

    if(red_occurrence)
        scrollToFirstRedAlarmOccurence(red_occurrence);
    else
        null
</script>
```

After clicking on the link and table shows, nothing happens (like script doesn't work). I expect it to scroll to the first red occurrence from a huge dataset. After I scroll the table up I would see another later red occurrencies. Below actual and expected results as pics:

[Actual res.] -> https://ibb.co/1zn4ty9
[Expected res.] -> https://ibb.co/Jy6FrL6

Comment: you should add full html and js here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ox1mbc8w/

Comment: can you convert to html only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters for 'getElementsByClassName' are incorrect. Use them as following.

```
<script>
  function scrollToFirstRedAlarmOccurence(red_occurrence) {
    // make jQuery object for first element
    $('tbody').animate({
      scrollTop: $(red_occurrence[0]).offset().top,
    }, 2000);
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    // select "font-red" classed elements
    var red_occurrence = document.getElementsByClassName("font-red"); // you can use jQuery selector too
    if(red_occurrence.length) { // check for array length
      scrollToFirstRedAlarmOccurence(red_occurrence);
    }
  }, 1000); // wait for DOM to render
</script>
```

Basically, you can debug your code to check if they are getting correct values. I have made some correction which would work for your case.

Comment: Ok, I used your modified code but it doesn't work. Now I have to wait until all datas will be loaded and then have to scroll to the last element of the **red_occurence** array. I've just made a simple modific. \n```setTimeout(() =>
                        {
                            var red_occurrence = document.getElementsByClassName("font-red");
                            var first_red_occurrence = red_occurrence[red_occurrence.length-1];
                            scrollToFirstRedAlarmOccurrence(first_red_occurrence);

                        }, 10000);```

Comment: Does the modified solution works? I see that you are waiting for 10 seconds. I assume that there is an AJAX call and those DOM elements get generated after its success response. If so, I will suggest adding these checks under the success handler. This way you can be sure that your code will work even if the AJAX call takes more than expected time.

Comment: No, my modified code doesn't work. I dont know much about AJAX. Could you tell me what is wrong in my code here [link](http://snippi.com/s/86q4m7e)? I want to save **first_red_occurrence** after all data will be loaded. Result for console.log shows that  **first_red_occurrence** points at last element but console.log runs multiple times (num of runs is equal to num of rows?).

Comment: As you can see the last element in Firefox console points at earliest alarm signal and THIS row should be display at top in tbody. [link](https://ibb.co/pzZhBVw)

Comment: I have updated your [sample code](http://snippi.com/s/el146bv) slightly. The code would work properly if triggered at the correct time. "DOMContentLoad" has a different use case. Replace it with a different event handler. You can keep it under a separate function as well. You need to just trigger it when your target DOM elements have been added.

Comment: Do you know how to get a parent element (#tab_content) for child element (td.font-red") ? I guess properly way to scroll is to point to tr, not to td. thanks for sample code

Comment: Find parent element using [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp) and [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/parent/). You can choose whichever approach you like. I will suggest going with jQuery as it will be much shorter.

Comment: Ok everything works like a charm :) Thanks Sujit for great tips!

Comment: To ignore the hidden row, use [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not). You would need to use this selector with jQuery. For offset, just add some buffer +/- 50px if it is difficult to exactly target the offset position of the target element.

Comment: I just added "hard value" at the end of scrollTop instrucion. In my case "-120" fit ideally but I know itdepends on screen resolution. For now its a good solution.